# Why is wordpress searching for @2x images?

Tags: images, templates

I've created some images for my site with the following path:

```
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/my-image.png
```

I edited my sites HTML to include this image (and other's like it). Now in my console I have a whole bunch of error messages:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -

/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/images/my-image@2x.png
```

I looked up @2x and I found that it has to do with different pixel density images. But why is it even trying to find this image? I didn't tell it to. Is this something wordpress does automatically? Do I have to create a @2x image for every image I add to my site? And why is it searching the assets folder?

Comment: Disable your plugins, switch to a default theme, empty all caches and there you'll see the answer. The answer is _Nothing of asked_.

Comment: @MaxYudin I dont have any plugins installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite having no plugins installed through wordpress, I did have retina.min.js being enqueued in my `functions.php` file from the template I downloaded.

Retina.min.js (source: http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) looks for high resolution versions (denoted with suffix @2x right before the extension) of each image in your site and attempts to replace them if any are found. Since I did not plan on using this feature for the time being, I commented it out of my `functions.php` file and I now have a clean console.

Comment: It sounds like this is an issue with the theme you're using, not with WordPress itself. Correct?

Comment: @PatJ Yeah, At first I thought it was an issue with WordPress itself when I posted the question. I was delighted to find that I was wrong. It was a problem with the HTML template that I downloaded and converted to a wordpress theme (or more specifically that I didnn't understand what I was converting).

Comment: Please be [respectful to one another](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - I've removed some of these comments.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Greatly appreciated. I know this isn't a discussion area, but I am new here. Is there a resource that details how to properly ask questions? I'd like to know why my question was down-voted so that I can better formulate ones for future posts - Or at least a place to ask such questions rather than in the comment section of an answer like this (clearly the wrong place)

Comment: @MatthewSirkin You can review our help section, [topics you can ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [topics you shouldn't ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Check out some of the [most upvoted questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). Usually, well received questions are general WordPress functionality questions and **not** theme specific, plugins specific, or system specific.